# C# - Sorting a ListBox containing key/value pairs using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, listbox

I have a list box control that contains key value pairs delimited by an "=" sign.

Example:

hot=cold

fast=slow

high=low

blue=red

I have two buttons, one that will sort the list by key and the other will sort the list by pair.

How could I do this using LINQ?

Comment: you should sort before you add the items to the list box, can you show how you populate the list box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sortedByKey = items.OrderBy(x => x.Split('=')[0]);
var sortedByValue = items.OrderBy(x => x.Split('=')[1]);
```

Those are queries that will order the items by the correct portion of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Sort by Key:

```
    myList.OrderBy(i => i.Split('=')[0])
```

Sort by Value:

```
    myList.OrderBy(i => i.Split('=')[1])
```